# What is a simple system of local coefficients?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles, fibration

In the context of spectral sequences of fibrations I have often seen the condition that a fibration has a simple system of local coefficients.

Unfortunately I don't know what this means, and google searches are not helpful.

> What does it mean for a fibration to have a simple system of local coefficients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One on which the $\pi_1$ of the base acts trivially.

Comment: See http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/steenrodco.pdf